# Linking a website to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have a website whose code contains a lot of computation (mostly in Python). Is there a way to perform those computations on Google App Engine every time and just return the results to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what App Engine is designed for.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Google App Engine is to deploy both web and mobile backends with the language, framework and libraries you see fit. You don't have to worry about the infrastructure, just the code. You can even use your [custom domain](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains) to deploy the app.

Since you want to use Python for your application, you can check these tutorials on how to deploy your app on an App Engine environment. It could be either a [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart) or a [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart) environment (depending on your [needs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/)).

Once the app is deployed, the users can access the website linked to it and perform their operations through the app.